# ASP.NET Core API search parameters from path/route

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-core

I am porting a PHP/[CI](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html) API that uses `$params = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc()` so that it can accept GET requests with many combinations, such as:

- https://server/properties/search/beds/3/page/1/sort/price_desc
- https://server/properties/search/page/2/lat/34.1/lon/-119.1
- https://server/properties/search
- etc

With lots of code like:

```
$page = 1;
if (!empty($params['page'])) {
    $page = (int)$params['page'];
}
```

### The two ASP.NET Core 2.1 techniques I've tried both seem like a kludge so I would appreciate any guidance on a better solution:

1) Conventional routing with catchall:

```
app.UseMvc(routes => {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Properties}/{action=Search}/{*params}"
                );
            });
```

> But now I have to parse the `params` string for the key/value pairs and am not able to take advantage of model binding.

2) Attribute routing:

```
    [HttpGet("properties/search")]
    [HttpGet("properties/search/beds/{beds}")]
    [HttpGet("properties/search/beds/{beds}/page/{page}")]
    [HttpGet("properties/search/page/{page}/beds/{beds}")]
    public IActionResult Search(int beds, double lat, double lon, int page = 1, int limit = 10) {
}
```

> Obviously putting every combination of allowed search parameters and values is tedious.

#### Changing the signature of these endpoints is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `FromPath` value provider

What you are wanting is to bind a complex model to part of the url path. Unfortunately, ASP.NET Core does not have a built-in `FromPath` binder. Fortunately, though, we can build our own.

Here is an [example `FromPathValueProvider` in GitHub](https://github.com/shaunluttin/asp-net-core-from-path-value-provider) that has the following result:

[image]

Basically, it is binding `domain.com/controller/action/key/value/key/value/key/value`. This is different than what either the `FromRoute` or the `FromQuery` value providers do.

## Use the `FromPath` value provider

Create a route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "properties-search",
    template: "{controller=Properties}/{action=Search}/{*path}"
);
```

Add the `[FromPath]` attribute to your action:

```
public IActionResult Search([FromPath]BedsEtCetera model)
{
    return Json(model);
}
```

And magically it will bind the `*path` to a complex model:

```
public class BedsEtCetera 
{
    public int Beds { get; set; }
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public string Sort { get; set; }
}
```

## Create the `FromPath` value provider

Create a new attribute based on [`FromRoute`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/FromRouteAttribute.cs).

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter | AttributeTargets.Property, 
    AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class FromPath : Attribute, IBindingSourceMetadata, IModelNameProvider
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public BindingSource BindingSource => BindingSource.Custom;

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Create a new IValueProviderFactory base on [`RouteValueProviderFactory`.](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/a5f3a6425e57f43a1d7e7ebf86553d8c35391242/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/RouteValueProviderFactory.cs)

```
public class PathValueProviderFactory : IValueProviderFactory
{
    public Task CreateValueProviderAsync(ValueProviderFactoryContext context)
    {
        var provider = new PathValueProvider(
            BindingSource.Custom, 
            context.ActionContext.RouteData.Values);

        context.ValueProviders.Add(provider);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Create a new IValueProvider base on [`RouteValueProvider`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/a736441ca5ac7524f4ed0d9c33370becb523c778/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/RouteValueProvider.cs).

```
public class PathValueProvider : IValueProvider
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> _values { get; }

    public PathValueProvider(BindingSource bindingSource, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        if(!values.TryGetValue("path", out var path)) 
        {
            var msg = "Route value 'path' was not present in the route.";
            throw new InvalidOperationException(msg);
        }

        _values = (path as string).ToDictionaryFromUriPath();
    }

    public bool ContainsPrefix(string prefix) => _values.ContainsKey(prefix);

    public ValueProviderResult GetValue(string key)
    {
        key = key.ToLower(); // case insensitive model binding
        if(!_values.TryGetValue(key, out var value)) {
            return ValueProviderResult.None;
        }

        return new ValueProviderResult(value);
    }
}
```

The `PathValueProvider` uses a `ToDictionaryFromUriPath` extension method.

```
public static class StringExtensions {
    public static Dictionary<string, string> ToDictionaryFromUriPath(this string path) {
        var parts = path.Split('/');
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        for(var i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
        {
            if(i % 2 != 0) continue;
            var key = parts[i].ToLower(); // case insensitive model binding
            var value = parts[i + 1];
            dictionary.Add(key, value);
        }

        return dictionary;
    }
}
```

Wire things together in your `Startup` class.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc()
            .AddMvcOptions(options => 
                options.ValueProviderFactories.Add(new PathValueProviderFactory()));
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseMvc(routes => {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "properties-search",
                template: "{controller=Properties}/{action=Search}/{*path}"
            );
        });
    }
}
```

Here is [a working sample on GitHub](https://github.com/shaunluttin/asp-net-core-from-path-value-provider).

Answer (score 2):

#### Edit

[My other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51111295/1108891) is a better option.

#### General Idea

`$params = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc()` turns a URI into an associative array, which is basically a .NET `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. We can do something similar in ASP.NET Core. Lets say we have the following routes.

```
app.UseMvc(routes => {
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "properties-search",
        template: "{controller=Properties}/{action=Search}/{*params}"
    );
});
```

#### Bind Uri Path to Dictionary

Action

```
public class PropertiesController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Search(string slug)
    {
        var dictionary = slug.ToDictionaryFromUriPath();
         return Json(dictionary);
    }
}
```

Extension Method

```
public static class UrlToAssocExtensions
{
    public static Dictionary<string, string> ToDictionaryFromUriPath(this string path) {
        var parts = path.Split('/');
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        for(var i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
        {
            if(i % 2 != 0) continue;
            var key = parts[i];
            var value = parts[i + 1];
            dictionary.Add(key, value);
        }

        return dictionary;
    }
}
```

The result is an associative array based on the URI path.

```
{
   "beds": "3",
   "page": "1",
   "sort": "price_desc"
}
```

> But now I have to parse the params string for the key/value pairs and am not able to take advantage of model binding.

## Bind Uri Path to Model

If you want model binding for this, then we need to go a step further.

Model

```
public class BedsEtCetera 
{
    public int Beds { get; set; }
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public string Sort { get; set; }
}
```

Action

```
public IActionResult Search(string slug)
{
    BedsEtCetera model = slug.BindFromUriPath<BedsEtCetera>();
    return Json(model);
}
```

Additional Extension Method

```
public static TResult BindFromUriPath<TResult>(this string path)
{
    var dictionary = path.ToDictionaryFromUriPath();
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(json);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you are looking at this from the wrong perspective.

Create a model:

```
public class FiltersViewModel
    {
        public int Page { get; set; } = 0;
        public int ItemsPerPage { get; set; } = 20;
        public string SearchString { get; set; }
        public string[] Platforms { get; set; }
    }
```

API Endpoint:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetResults([FromRoute] ViewModels.FiltersViewModel filters)
{
    // process the filters here
}
```

Result Object (dynamic)

```
public class ListViewModel
{
    public object[] items;
    public int totalCount = 0;
    public int filteredCount = 0;
}
```

Comment: `FromQuery` binds to the query string (after the `?` in the URL) not to the path. As a result, it will not work for the `/key/value/key/value/...` pattern.

Comment: My bad, typed too quickly ;)